# UIImage appears to take up space beyond the bounds of its UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I have an application where by I take a picture and then go on to present this image in a different UIViewController.  However, the resulting UIImage appears to expand beyond the bounds at which I set the UIImageView.  The content mode is 'Aspect fill'

After taking the picture, the following method is called:
CaptureImageViewController:

```
func presentCapturedImage(image: CGImage, observationObj: VNRectangleObservation) -> Void {
    print("HERE!")

    let prevVC  = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "prevcrop") as! PreviewCropViewController
    prevVC.cgImg = image
    prevVC.uiImageEXIF = uiImageEXIF
    prevVC.ObserObj = observationObj

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(prevVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

PresentingViewController calls the following in its viewDidLoad():

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgPreViewOutlet: UIImageView!


guard
        let img = self.cgImg,
        let imgEXIF = self.uiImageEXIF else{return}

    let uiImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: img)

    self.imgPreViewOutlet.image = uiImage
```

The UIViewController that I use to present the image:

[image]

The Constraints of the lower UIView holding the UIButton:

[image]

The constraints of the UIImageView:

[image]

The resulting view - you can see the image covers almostall of the crop button:

[image]

Comment: Have you set the imageView to `clipsToBounds`? AspectFill can scale the image outside the bounds if it isn't clipped.

Comment: @JonJ - thank you. that was the solution. if you would like to add that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Beware when using `aspectFill` in UIImageViews. If `clipsToBounds` is not true, the image will probably extend outside the frame.

This happens as the image is scaled in such a way to fully fill the image view frame. If the proportions of the image and frame aren't exactly identical, the image will extend outside the frame.